# SQL XQuery Selector for Key/Value Pairs

Tags: sql, xml, xquery, xquery-sql

I have some xml in a column like this.

```
<ScopedWorkflowConfiguration xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/workflow/2012/xaml/activities">
  <appSettings>
    <AppSetting>
      <Key>CurrentWebUri</Key>
      <Value>http://myurl.org</Value>
    </AppSetting>
    <AppSetting>
      <Key>SomethingElse</Key>
      <Value>1</Value>
    </AppSetting>
    <AppSetting>
      <Key>AnotherThing</Key>
      <Value>420</Value>
    </AppSetting>
  </appSettings>
</ScopedWorkflowConfiguration>
```

Trying to select the value of the Value node.

```
;WITH Casted AS (SELECT t.Id, t.[Configuration] As XmlData FROM dbo.MyTable AS t)
Select Distinct
     Id
    ,pv.value('//*:Key="CurrentWebUri"/Value', 'nvarchar(max)') As CurrentWebUri
From
    Casted
    Cross Apply Casted.XmlData.nodes(N'//*:ScopedWorkflowConfiguration//*:appSettings//*:AppSetting') AS A(pv)
```

I know I am close -- but I have having trouble with the syntax here: ***//*:Key="CurrentWebUri"/Value***

The Query above results in this error:

> A node or set of nodes is required for /

Can you help?

Adding a result set for reference to further clarify what I am after:

```
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| ID | CurrentWebUri    | SomethingElse    |  AnotherThing    |
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  1 | example.org      |        1         |       420        |
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  2 | example.com      |        6         |       29         |
+----+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default namespace declaration was missing, and XPath expressions were off. And with the latest clarification of the desired output, a dynamic SQL for PIVOTing is needed.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
USE tempdb;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tbl;

CREATE TABLE dbo.tbl (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, [Configuration] xml);

INSERT INTO dbo.tbl ([Configuration])
VALUES ('<ScopedWorkflowConfiguration xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/workflow/2012/xaml/activities">
    <appSettings>
        <AppSetting>
            <Key>CurrentWebUri</Key>
            <Value>http://myurl.org</Value>
        </AppSetting>
        <AppSetting>
            <Key>SomethingElse</Key>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </AppSetting>
        <AppSetting>
            <Key>AnotherThing</Key>
            <Value>420</Value>
        </AppSetting>
    </appSettings>
</ScopedWorkflowConfiguration>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/workflow/2012/xaml/activities')
SELECT TOP(1) @columns = STUFF([Configuration].query('for $s in /ScopedWorkflowConfiguration/appSettings/AppSetting/Key
                           return <x>{concat(",",$s)}</x>')
                   .value('.','varchar(max)'),1,1,'')
FROM dbo.tbl;

SET @SQL = 
N';WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT ''http://schemas.microsoft.com/workflow/2012/xaml/activities''), rs AS
( 
    SELECT ID
        , c.value(''(Key/text())[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') AS [Key]
        , c.value(''(Value/text())[1]'', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)'') AS [Value]
    FROM dbo.tbl as tbl
        CROSS APPLY tbl.[Configuration].nodes(''/ScopedWorkflowConfiguration/appSettings/AppSetting'') AS t(c)
)
SELECT ID,' + @columns + N' FROM rs
PIVOT (
    MAX([Value])
    FOR [Key] IN (' + @columns + N')
) AS pvt;
';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

> Output

```
+----+------------------+---------------+--------------+
| ID |  CurrentWebUri   | SomethingElse | AnotherThing |
+----+------------------+---------------+--------------+
|  1 | http://myurl.org |             1 |          420 |
+----+------------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks - I should have been more clear about the requirements: I need the query to be able to target a specific node value such as 'CurrentWebUri'. Using the index [1] will not be sufficient.

Comment: I adjusted the SQL by adding a predicate. Check it out now.

Comment: @JasonSmith, just to add to this great answer (+1 from my side): You can use `sql:variable("@SearchFor")` instead of the literal in the xquery predicate. This allows to declare a T-SQL-Variable `DECLARE @SearchFor VARCHAR(100)='CurrentWebUri';` in order to get this more generic. Similar we have `sql:column()` to include any column value of the current row.

Comment: @Yitzhak, I don't know where I went wrong communicating what I am after -- but I updated the original question to show a result set that I am trying to achieve. I hope this helps clarify things. Let me know.

Comment: @JasonSmith, I modified the answer to accommodate your latest clarification.